# Docker compose volumes_from not updating after rebuild

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Imagine two containers: webserver (1) is hosting static HTML files that need to be built form templates inside a data volume container (2).

`docker-compose.yml` file looks something like this:

```
version: "2"

services:
  webserver:
    build: ./web
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes_from:
      - templates
  templates:
    build: ./templates
```

`Dockerfile` for `templates` service looks like this

```
FROM ruby:2.3
# ... there is more but that is should not be important
WORKDIR /tmp
COPY ./Gemfile /tmp/Gemfile
RUN bundle install
COPY ./source /tmp/source
RUN bundle exec middleman build --clean
VOLUME /tmp/build
```

When I run `docker-compose up` everything is working as expected: templates are built, webserver hosts them and you can view them in the browser.

Problem is, when I update the `./source` and restart/rebuild the setup, the files the webserver hosts are still the old ones, although the log shows that the container was rebuilt - at least the last three layers after `COPY ./source /tmp/source`. So the changes inside the `source` folder are picked up by the rebuilt but I'm not able to get the changes shown in the browser.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Compose [preserves volumes when containers are recreated](https://docker.github.io/compose/overview/#/preserve-volume-data-when-containers-are-created), which is probably why you are seeing the old files.

Generally it is not a good idea to use volumes for source code (or in this case static html files).  Volumes are for data you want to persist, like data in a database. Source code changes with each version of the image, so doesn't really belong in a volume.

Instead of using a data volume container for these files, you can use a `builder` container to compile them and a `webserver` service to host them. You'll need to add a `COPY` to the `webserver` `Dockerfile` to include the files.

To accomplish this you would change your `docker-compose.yml` to this:

```
version: "2"
services:
  webserver:
    image: myapp:latest
    ports: ["80:80"]
```

Now you just need to build `myapp:latest`. You could write a script which:

- builds the builder container
- runs the builder container
- builds the `myapp` container

You can also use a tool like [dobi](http://dnephin.github.io/dobi/) instead of writing a script (disclaimer: I am the author of this tool). There is [an example of building a minimal docker image](https://github.com/dnephin/dobi/tree/master/examples/minimal-docker-image) which is very similar to what you're trying to do.

Your `dobi.yaml` might look something like this:

```
image=builder:
  image: myapp-dev
  context: ./templates

job=templates:
  use: builder

image=webserver:
  image: myapp
  tags: [latest]
  context: .
  depends: [templates]

compose=serve:
  files: [docker-compose.yml]
  depends: [webserver]
```

Now if you run `dobi serve` it will do all the steps for you. Each step will only be run if files have changed.

Comment: thank you for the reply.will take a look at `dobi`. in the meantime I also stumbled upon "named volumes" - could they work? but I also think they can't yet be used with docker cloud :(

Comment: you could run a container to update the contents of a named volume, that would work better than `volumes_from`.

Comment: do you know if named volumes are supported on docker cloud right now?